# How to add new key and value to array using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 object in array, for the first object i want to add `ifContrbtd:false` and for remaining 2 objects i want to add `ifContrbtd:true`. I have tried like following but it added `ifContrbtd:true` to 2nd and 3rd object, nothing is added to first object.

```
for (var key in res.result) {
    var ifContributed = false;
    if(res.result[key].newField != undefined){
        ifContributed = true;
        res.result[key]['ifContrbtd']=ifContributed;
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the assignment outside the `if` condition so that `ifContributed = false`  is assigned for objects having `newField`. Right now nothing will be assined if it is defined:

```js
for (var key in res.result) {
  var ifContributed = false;
  if (res.result[key].newField != undefined) {
    ifContributed = true;
  }
  res.result[key]['ifContrbtd'] = ifContributed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put assign value to res.result[key]['ifContrbtd'] after the if statement not inside it.

Just below 3 lines will solve your issue:

```
for (var key in res.result) {
    var ifContributed = (res.result[key].newField != undefined);
    res.result[key]['ifContrbtd'] = ifContributed;
}
```